# Laravel installation & configuration 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

Im new to laravel.I've downloaded the laravel 5.2 Via Composer Create-Project.
**composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.2.*"**
Im using xampp
When i run the project in my chrome browser http://localhost/blog/,
`[image: It displays like this.]

Hope help & support

Comment: either set the `virtual host` to your project where `document route` is upto your `public` directory, or use `php artisan:serve` command

Comment: Check step 4 from this [link](http://vijayasankar.me.pn/blog/2017/01/17/installing-laravel-framework-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-aws-ec2/)

Comment: Use  `http://localhost/blog/public` instead of `http://localhost/blog/` Or you can create virtualhost for perfect URL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy `.htaccess` from the `public` directory and paste it in the `root` directory

rename the `server.php` at the root directory to `index.php`

visit `http://localhost/blog/`

Comment: Very thanks for your help..This was very usefull for my problem

Comment: you are most welcome @HelenaHannahG, glad could help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

First open terminal/cmd and write you project full path.
After that run `php artisan serve` command and it will start the server and give you a url like (http://127.0.0.1:8000).Open the URL in browser. You can see your project running.

Hope this help you

Answer (score -1):

You need to create virtual host for your project.

`<VirtualHost laravel.dev:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public"
  ServerAdmin laravel.dev
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\blog">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

For more information check this [guide](https://www.codementor.io/magarrent/how-to-install-laravel-5-xampp-windows-du107u9ji).